# How to use OpenTK (OpenGL) with MonoGame?

Tags: c#, xna, opengl, monogame, opentk

So I've been making a snake game using MonoGame (DirectX Only). I added movement, controls, feeding and growing in length. I wanted to add smooth animations to the game because the snake is just made out of 32 X 32 squares currently and it moves by 32 pixels (1 square) so it's not smooth at all. So I thought I could use the OpenGL template which has both the MonoGame(XNA) framework and the OpenTK framework so that I can make smooth animations with skewing when changing direction for example. The way I have in mind is to make a "skeleton" for the snake and the textures of the body parts would be skewed (or deformed or whatever) to take the shape of that skeleton. But OpenTK doesn't seem to be set up with the MonoGame framework. So can someone point me towards a way of using it to accomplish my goal?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Normally you just select the MonoGame GL template in Visual Studio and it just works. What's the actual error you're getting? Also, it's unclear why you think changing to GL has something to do with smooth animations. You should be able to achieve the same with either.

Comment: But I want to skew the sprites

Comment: And there's no error it's just that I don't know where to get started with the GL template to start drawing GL stuff

Comment: The fact that you're using DX or GL shouldn't make any difference. MonoGame is intended to work the same way. If you're making calls into OpenTK directly you're bypassing MonoGame and losing some of the benefits. I think you should take a step back and rethink your question.

Comment: So if use SpriteBatch functions in GL template I'm using OpenGL?

Comment: Exactly. So it sounds like the question you're really trying to ask is how the skew sprites with MonoGame.